# how can i make a database for pycord?

Tags: python, sqlite, discord, pycord

I'm currently programming a Discord Bot. I'm pretty new to pycord and I wanted to make a command that saves a str in a databasel
if anyone could show an example for it i`ll be so happy

i tried using SQlite but i couldnt find any good tutorials on it

Comment: here are the sqlite docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html,  here is a link to google: https://www.google.com

Comment: Welcome to SO! Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75450621/edit) your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [full text of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), all as formatted text in the question itself. Do not post images of text. The code should be a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Py-cord is pretty irrelevant in this question, as you can use pretty much any database that you want.

A good alternative to SQlite would be pymongo. It's very simple, and you can learn it pretty quickly. It's also free.

If you want something locally stored, just use JSON. It's the quickest way to develop a storage system.